# How to build a function when parameters are combination of string and array(object) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, protractor, webdriver-io

I'm reading values from excel and then trying to build a function based on parameters it has.

It will have dynamic parameters in combination of strings and arrays as per its usage in function.

My sample code as below

excel

```
A1 = 'test'
A2 = ['test1','test2']
```

JS

```
function test(params){
..
var paramValues = params.split(","); //params1=A1, params2=A2 here params is sheet name
    if(paramValues != null)
    {
        for(var pi = 0;pi<paramValues.length;pi++)
        {
            index = paramValues[pi].substring(6) //returns value of row number as index
            var paramCellVal = await excel.getCellValue("A"+index) //returns 'test' in iteration 1,['test1','test2'] in iteration 2
            actualParams.push(paramCellVal) //push values to array
        }
        console.log(actualParams+"actualParams"+typeof(actualParams)) //returns object
        action =  findFunction(...actualParams);
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

function findFunction(...actualParams){
    run(...actualParams)
}

function run(param1, param2){
console.log(param1, typeof(param1))
console.log(param2, typeof(param2))
console.log(param2[0], typeof(param2[0]))
console.log(param2[0], typeof(param2[1]))
}
```

expected output:

```
'test', string
['test1','test2'], object
'test1', string
'test2', string
```

actual output:

```
'test', string
['test1','test2'], string
[, string
', string
```

My expectation is to build dynamic function with different set of variables, hence used spread syntax.

Comment: Could be missing something here, but why not just test the param to see if it's an array? Array.isArray ( param ). If it is, you know it's an array. If it isn't, based on the fact you know it's either strings or arrays, you know it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function run(param1, param2){
console.log(param1, typeof(param1))
console.log(JSON.stringify(param2), typeof(JSON.stringify(param2)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(param2[0]), typeof(JSON.stringify(param2[0])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(param2[1]), typeof(JSON.stringify(param2[1])))
}
```